# Array de tamaño indefinido java, ¿se puede?

Tags: java

tengo que hacer el siguiente ejercicio:

> Realiza una función que reciba un array bidimensional y muestre por
>   consola la suma de cada fila y de cadacolumna. El número de filas no
>   tiene por qué ser igual al número de columnas.

Mi mayor problema es con los arrays irregulares, es decir, por ejemplo este:

```java
        int array[][] = { {2, 4, 6},
                          {3, 1, 7, 7} };
```

Tengo que hacer una función que devuelva en un nuevo array la suma, de como dice el enunciado, columnas y filas.

Solo tengo hecho una parte muy pequeña del código, la idea, por así decirlo, porque me trae loco lo de crear un array cuyo tamaño final no sé.

```java
    public static int[][] sumArray(int[][] array) {

        int[][] result = null;

        // Suma de columnas.
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // Primera dimensión
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) { // Segunda dimensión
                result[i][j] += array[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
```

Gracias!

Comment: creo que lo mejor es que trates los arrays como objetos derivados de Iterable, como un ArrayList por ejemplo.

Comment: Una pregunta importante: qué pasó cuando usaste tu código como está? La sugerencia es siempre intentarlo hasta que no sepas cómo hacer que funcione :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo primero que necesitas es saber el número de filas y de columnas que vas a sumar. La parte de las filas es fácil, sólo tienes que comprobar el tamaño del array recibido:

```
int filas = array.length;
```

Para las columnas nos tendremos que quedar con el tamaño máximo de todas ellas, recorriendo cada fila y ver cuál es la más larga:

```
int columnas = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
    columnas = Math.max(columnas, array[i].length);
}

Una vez que tienes estos datos, puedes crear dos arrays para guardar la suma de las filas y la suma de las columnas:

int [] sumaFilas = new int[filas];
int [] sumaColumnas = new int[columnas];
//ambas se inicializarán con todas sus celdas a 0
```

Y ahora sólo tienes que recorrer todas las celdas e ir sumando los valores donde corresponde, con el bucle que ya tienes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) { // importante, array[i]!
        sumaFilas[i] += array[i][j];
        sumaColumnas[j] += array[i][j];
    }
}
```

Ya sólo te quedará mostrar el resultado por consola:

```
System.out.println("La suma de cada fila da:" + Arrays.toString(sumaFilas));
System.out.println("La suma de cada columna da:" + Arrays.toString(sumaColumna));
```

Comment: Con Java8 podemos resolver el tamaño máximo de la siguiente manera:
 int size = Arrays.stream(array).map(row -> row.length).max(Integer::compare).get();

Comment: No me he querido meter en cosas avanzadas, parece que aún no conocen las listas (List, ArrayList... y meter streams ya sería demasiado